# Using stat() to check if file exists and we have read permissions

Tags: linux, stat

I would like to check if a file exists and the user has read permissions on it in C++ (Linux, Debian). After some research I found that I should be using stat() for this.

```
struct stat buf;
stat("file", &buf);
cout << buf.st_mode << "\n\n";
```

When I output st_mode (which according to me manual should contain the protection info) I get `0`. I don't know how to use it to interpret the access rights on the file.

Also I don't how I can use stat() to check if the file actually exists. Should I be checking if stat() returns `-1` indicating an error, which would mean he can't find the file?

Comment: You should definitely check the return value of stat. The struct won't contain any useful information if stat didn't return 0.

Comment: Don't use `stat()`, use `access()`. It does exactly what you want without requiring examination of a structure.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see here [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) when '-1' is returned you have to look to `errno` to see what the actual error is, there are several errors listed in the link. I think by the way that `access()` is the proper api to be called as someone else already suggested.